# Examples for Winsock?

Tags: c++, resources, winsock

What do you guys recommend for a resource for winsock?

I have an assignment that we have only have a few days to do that needs to send a simple packet using UDP (and receive the same type of packet).

I am fairly familiar with C# sockets but nothing with C++.

Any tips or resources?

Comment: MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just a note about TCP/UDP: TCP packets are "guaranteed" to be delivered, UDP are not (they favor speed over reliability and may even arrive out-of-order.) So *expect* this and handle it appropriately for best results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some are as follows:

- [Winsock Programming](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2241&lngWId=3)
- [Winsock Networking Tutorial (C++)](http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/)
- [WinSock Tutorial](http://www.nullterminator.net/winsock.html)

Answer (score 5):

Besides the MSDN resource "[Getting Started with Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28VS.85%29.aspx)" mentioned already I would recommend the "[Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/)" on tangentsoft.net.

Answer (score 3):

You need UDP, so use

1. sendto()
2. recvfrom()

APIs (Windows).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740148%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about the [step-by-step guide to getting started with Windows Sockets programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28VS.85%29.aspx) from the Winsock documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more advanced than you need right now but...

I have a series of (rather old) articles on writing scalable servers using Winsock and IO Completion Ports and a free framework of code.

The code and links to the articles are available [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).